# Waiting until JSX files compiling is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

i am using the standalone version of babel together with react.js to use in browser and later in Android webview.
(no Application, Server, node.js, npm...)
When I create more REACT Components in different files, i run into component is not defined errors.

This is because babel is not finished with JSX compiling of the components when i try to access this
components in a page loaded function. Is there a method to wait until JSX compiling is complete?

Please help! i am new with REACT/Babel and found no solution the last couple of days :-((

Comment: Can you share some code or build configuration? I imagine it is because one thing is not hoisted. It might be a good idea using WebPack or run your code add the bottom of the compiled script file.

Comment: Share some code please.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, while implementing a solution to use react in my old school java app.

In dev mode i wanted to use my jsx files client side so that i can test them right away.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/react/vendor/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/assets/react/jsx/my-react-file-with-funtion.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
                myFunctionDefinedInMyJSXScript();
    });
</script>
```

But this it didn't work, got a

> myFunctionDefinedInMyJSXScript is undefined

Changing my function call script tag from "text/javascript" to "text/babel" solved it.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    $(function () {
                myFunctionDefinedInMyJSXScript();
    });
</script>
```